# How do I fix argv[1] in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

I have a problem with `argv[1]` in Python 3.8.2. This is my code:

```
from sys import *

def open_file(filename):
    print(filename)

def run():
    open_file(argv[1])

run()
```

And it shows error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*File*", line 9, in <module>
    run()
  File "*File*", line 7, in run
    open_file(argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Well what argument *did* you pass?

Comment: I started with file directory, then only file name, next just random words, nothing works

Comment: So give a [mre] showing that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you call the script with the argument?
Like this:

```
python myscript.py "First arg"
```

By the way,

```
from sys import *
```

is bad code. You should never do that.
If you want to import a whole module, better do it like that:

```
import sys
```

Then to refer desired variable use name_of_module.name_of_variable:

```
sys.argv[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

argv is a list of all parameters entered behind `python` on your command line separated by spaces.

example:
 foo.py:

```
from sys import argv
print(argv)
print(argv[0])
print(argv[1])
```

command line:

```
python foo.py 1 2 3
```

stdout:

```
['foo.py', '1', '2', '3']
foo.py
1
```